UnrecognizedPropertyException for classes annotated with Lombok annotations
I tried to map a DTO (Student) to a DAO (StudentEntity) using ObjectMapper's convertValue method:
new ObjectMapper().convertValue(student, StudentEntity.class);

However, I encountered the following exception:
2024-09-20T20:48:01.063+05:30  INFO 10444 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-20T20:48:01.064+05:30  INFO 10444 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-20T20:48:01.065+05:30  INFO 10444 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2024-09-20T20:48:01.210+05:30 ERROR 10444 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "firstName" (class com.icet.dao.StudentEntity), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.icet.dao.StudentEntity["firstName"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "firstName" (class com.icet.dao.StudentEntity), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.icet.dao.StudentEntity["firstName"])

But after adding the @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) annotation to the StudentEntity class, the exception did not occur.
My question is:
What are the possible reasons for this exception, and why does adding @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) resolve the issue?
Entity Class:
package com.icet.dao;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class StudentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;


    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String nic;
    private String email;
    private String batch;
    private String age;
}


Student Class:
package com.icet.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String nic;
    private String email;
    private String batch;
    private String age;
}


Service Class Method That Object Mapped:
public void registerStudent(Student student) {
        StudentEntity entity1 = new ObjectMapper()
                .convertValue(student,StudentEntity.class);

        //log.info(entity1.toString());
        repository.save(entity1);
    }

Full Stack Trace:
2024-09-20T20:48:01.063+05:30  INFO 10444 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-20T20:48:01.064+05:30  INFO 10444 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-20T20:48:01.065+05:30  INFO 10444 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2024-09-20T20:48:01.210+05:30 ERROR 10444 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "firstName" (class com.icet.dao.StudentEntity), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.icet.dao.StudentEntity["firstName"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "firstName" (class com.icet.dao.StudentEntity), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.icet.dao.StudentEntity["firstName"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:1153) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:2241) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1793) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1771) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:316) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4619) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4555) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.icet.service.impl.StudentServiceImpl.registerStudent(StudentServiceImpl.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.icet.controller.StudentController.registerStudent(StudentController.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]



Though, can you confirm if it actually resolves the issue rather than a silent failure? Is the entity constructed correctly?

Side note: I think its overkill to use Jackson objectmapper to convert a POJO to another POJO. See the documentation why. Maybe consider providing a copy constructor instead?

Simple answer:
Setter and getter are required for Jackson ObjectMapper which is
missing in your Entity class while doing the conversion.
Please add @Getter and @Setter from Lombok on top of the Entity class.

I'll start by saying that this isn't an ideal design for mapping your business domain to entities. There are libraries better suited for this task that could be built-in to your application's persistence layer design to automate mapping in an efficient way. (But if this is just a basic project I don't see any reason to switch your implementation)
As for your issue, the conversion is failing because there are no setters on the entity class. Add @Data or @Setter annotation on the entity or individual setters for the fields and it will work as expected. Just be aware that the conversion back to Student will require getters on the entity class as well.
The reason it works when ignoring unknown properties is because, since there are no setters on the entity, every property on Student is unknown to StudentEntity. When performing the conversion with this annotation, none of the properties are actually mapped to the entity class.
